# Capture search button event on an input with clear button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, cordova, onsen-ui

I have the following in my app html:

```
 <form>
     <input id="txt-search" type="search">
     <button id="btn-clear"><i icon="ion-android-cancel"></i></button>
 </form>
```

My JavaScript:

```
$( document ).on( "click", "#btn-clear", function( evt ) {

    evt.preventDefault();

    $( "#txt-search" ).val("");
    $( "#txt-search" ).focus();
    $( "#btn-clear" ).hide();

} );
```

The problem I am having is when the user clicks the "Search" button on the virtual keyboard in iOS the clear button is getting clicked. I don't understand why this is happening. The txt-search is in focus so it shouldn't be sending the event to the clear button. Any ideas on how I can get around this?

Answer (score 0):

Use a jQuery submit event, not a click, like this:

```js
$( "#txt-search" ).on( "submit", function( evt ) {

    evt.preventDefault();

    $( "#txt-search" ).val("");
    $( "#txt-search" ).focus();
    $( "#btn-clear" ).hide();

} );
```